# Queued Employees

Tags: java, queue

The following example shows how to implement a queue in an employee structure. I am looking for a review of the implementation:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class GenQueue<E> {
   private LinkedList<E> list = new LinkedList<E>();
   public void enqueue(E item) {
      list.addLast(item);
   }
   public E dequeue() {
      return list.poll();
   }
   public boolean hasItems() {
      return !list.isEmpty();
   }
   public int size() {
      return list.size();
   }
   public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {
      while (q.hasItems())
         list.addLast(q.dequeue());
   }
}
```

Here's a test class:

```
public class GenQueueTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      GenQueue<Employee> empList;
      empList = new GenQueue<Employee>();
      GenQueue<HourlyEmployee> hList;
      hList = new GenQueue<HourlyEmployee>();
      hList.enqueue(new HourlyEmployee("T", "D"));
      hList.enqueue(new HourlyEmployee("G", "B"));
      hList.enqueue(new HourlyEmployee("F", "S"));
      empList.addItems(hList);
      System.out.println("The employees' names are:");
      while (empList.hasItems()) {
         Employee emp = empList.dequeue();
         System.out.println(emp.firstName + " " 
         + emp.lastName);
      }
   }
}
```

And the `Employee` class:

```
class Employee {
   public String lastName;
   public String firstName;
   public Employee() {
   }
   public Employee(String last, String first) {
      this.lastName = last;
      this.firstName = first;
   }
   public String toString() {
      return firstName + " " + lastName;
   }
}

class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
   public double hourlyRate;
   public HourlyEmployee(String last, String first) {
      super(last, first);
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
The employees' name are:
T D
G B
F S
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## !The Queue

About the not-the-queue things:

- your Employee and HourlyEmployee classes have public fields (`firstname`, etc.) You should instead have 'getters' for them (like `getFirstName()`). I would recommend making those values 'final' as well, but I don't think this is central to your question about queues.
- Your code is generally well formatted. It's easy to read.
- The variable names are appropriate.

Basically, this is decent code. It looks like the code does the job too.... now, about the job....

## The Queue

What you have done is 'wrap' a LinkedList, and called it a queue. You have not actually implemented a queue. There is nothing wrong with doing this, but it does not add much value either. The confusion continues with your naming here.... For example, why is it called `empList` when it's a `GenQueue`?

Your generics are good on the `addItems()` though.

Unfortunately, it is 'bad practice' to modify the input value `q` in a method called `addItems()`... i.e. it should be called `transferItems` or something. I would expect a method like `addItems` to leave the items in the source, and copy them to the destination.

Out of interest, it would be interesting to present your code as an extension to a LinkedList, instead of a wrapper. Consider this:

```
class GenQueue<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
   public void enqueue(E item) {
      addLast(item);
   }
   public E dequeue() {
      return poll();
   }
   public boolean hasItems() {
      return !isEmpty();
   }
   public void addItems(GenQueue<? extends E> q) {
      while (q.hasItems())
         addLast(q.dequeue());
   }
}
```

Now your GenQueue *is* a Queue (java.util.Queue) and it is also a List, and it supports all the features that are already embedded in those implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and explaining/showing an example of what I can do to make it better and more clear as a queue.

Comment: Extending `LinkedList` makes your `GenQueue` more vurnerable, as methods from `List` can be called. Better to use encapsulation if you want to ensure proper behaviour.